# What is and how to calculate quartic interpolation?

Tags: interpolation

I was reading the [gist](https://gist.github.com/dfarhi/66ec9d760ae0c49a5c492c9fae93984a) on the reward function used in OpenAI Five, but I didn't understand the way they calculate health's reward.

This is what they state: *Hero health is scored according to a quartic interpolation between 0 (dead) and 1 (full health) to force heavier weight when the agent is near dying.*

I tried googling but didn't manage to find an easy enough explanation for me to understand. What exactly is *quartic interpolation* and how is it calculated?

I understand the normalization part of scoring it between 0 and 1, but how do they increase the weight of certain values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation of this point is a bit unclear, but since "the agent's reward is the increase in score from one tick to the next", presumably there is some function $h(x)$ that maps the health $x$ to a score.

If the function were $h(x) = x,$ a $0.1$ increase in health would give the same reward whether $x$ was near $0$ or near $1.$ But they wanted the reward to be greater if $x$ is near $0$, so they chose $h$ to be some other function.
"Quartic interpolation" suggests they chose a fourth-degree polynomial,
a function that can be written in the form $h(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e.$
They don't say *which* polynomial.
One possibility is $h(x) = (1 - x)^4 = x^4 - 4x^3 + 6x^2 - 4x + 1,$
but it could be something else.

Comment: Thank you, I finally understood it! I think the main problem I was having was always finding polynomial functions written in the form _h(x)=ax4+bx3+cx2+dx+e_. Presenting the example _h(x)=(1−x)4=x4−4x3+6x2−4x+1_ made much more sense to me, thanks!